# Master of Magic 1.3.1; trouble saving

Tags: master-of-magic

I'm running MOM 1.3.1 (the last Micro-prose Version; on win ten; dos box 0.74) and I am having trouble with keeping my saves, Lets say I will save a game. Then I will close dos-box and then turn off my computer, when I return to my computer (you know turning it on) I will attempt to resume the game, but I will have no saves what so ever. Any solutions?

EDIT

I haven't set up any folders or any thing for dosbox besides putting a shortcut to it on my desktop, **all im doing to run MOM is dragging the MAGIC.exe to the dosbox short-cut and letting go.**

Comment: There should be save files in your folder structure some where, but I'd need to know more about your system configuration to know where to point you. I'd check the folder where the game files are installed, and also the DOSBox folder. It's possible that they're being created, but there's a configuration issue where they're not being seen by the game.

Comment: DOSBox allows you to set up memory-mapped drives, right? Make sure you're saving to a real HDD

Comment: As KutuluMike said,  make sure that DosBox has a directory mounted as a drive. If you don't have a mount command in your autoexec.bat section of your dosbox.conf, then MoM will most likely be saving to DosBox's Z: drive, which is a virtual drive that is not persistent. See here http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/AUTOEXEC

Comment: @Fambida i mounted a C:\ drive and now it works, thanks y'all.